# How in Scala , trait "Null" can be instantiated producing "null"?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

From [the API doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Null.html) I found that `Null` is a trait, but it says its sole instance is `null`.

> ```
> abstract final class Null extends AnyRef
> ```
>
> **Null** is - together with [scala.Nothing](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Nothing.html) - at the bottom of the Scala type hierarchy.
>
> **Null** is a subtype of all reference types; its only instance is the **null** reference. Since **Null** is not a subtype of value types, null is not a member of any such type. For instance, it is not possible to assign **null** to a variable of type [scala.Int](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html).

How is it possible to instantiate a trait? Any simple example to realize this concept would really helpful.

Comment: `Null` isn't a trait. It's a class. Notice how the API doc you show there says "class", not "trait".

Answer (score 2):

You cannot instantiate an instance of the class `Null`, as it is abstract and final. `Null` is a figment of the compiler similar `Nothing`, used as a bottom-type for all reference types. That is, `Null` is a sub-type of any other type that inherits from `AnyRef`. Its only value is the null reference, but there is no way to instantiate the `Null` class and magically get a null reference. It differs from `Nothing` in that it *is* inhabited by a single value: `null`.

Therefore, if you assign `null` to an identifier, `Null` will be inferred as its type if you don't hint otherwise.

```
scala> val a = null
a: Null = null
```